# Can we make a subgroup of a group by selecting exactly one element from each distinct left cosets of a subgroup of the given group?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ ; can we select exactly one element from each distinct left coset of $H$ such that the set of all those elements form a subgroup of $G$ ? How do we characterize those groups and for given groups , those subgroups , for which it is possible ?

Comment: You can't for the even integers as a subgroup of the integers. Are you asking if this is ever possible?

Comment: For $G$ finite, you can do this if, and only if, $H$ has a complement $K$ in $G$ : $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=1$.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker: you can't for every (non-trivial proper) subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$, as if such a subgroup exists (in any group $G$), then its order is equal to the index of $H$.  But

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa How is $G$ being finite relevanf here?

Comment: @ Derek Holt: To apply "$|G|=|HK|$ implies $G=HK$".

Comment: Ok, one can drop this assumption (I didn't noticed that one can prove $G=HK$ directly).

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa : Can you please demonstrate a proof of your claim ?

Comment: @Saun Dev.  Hints: Assume that the we can choose a transversal $K$ which forms a subgroup.  Then, for any $g\in G$, $gH$ contains an element $k \in K$; hence $gH=kH$, it follows that $g\in HK$, and we have...Conversely, assume that $K$ is a complement for $H$ in $G$.  Then any $g \in G$ can be written as $kh$, with...; it follows that $k\in gH$.  Now, if $k,k' \in gH$, then $k^{-1}k'\in H$; but $K\cap H=1$, so.... Please complete the argument (you can post it as answer).  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If $H$ is a retract of $G$ or a kernel of a retraction of $G$ then it is possible (in other words: if $H$ is a semidirect factor of $G$). But I am not sure if that exhausts all possibilities.